# Creating representable signature of tags

Tags: tags, compression, signature

Lets say I have items with assigned tags to them, like "blue", "big", "flexible". Lets say I also have a dictionary of all possible tags.

Now the question is : how can I compress all the tags to single small *signature*, lets say a floating point number. The requirement is that items with similar tags have similar signature.

All the tags are known forever. The signature should be relatively small, e.g. a floating point number, or a set of few integers.

Comment: Are there any other assumptions? Limited number of tags per item? Set of tags is fixed forever? Items and tags are stored in a SQL database?

Comment: Just updated the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I think the scheme of boiling this down to a single number isn't worth it. Just use a 16-bit int or a 32-bit int to represent a tag. And use one of those fields for each tag you want to apply to an item. Your quest to save space will just increase complexity unnecessarily.

Assign each tag an ID number. You may want to store the mapping of tags to IDs in a separate table. Call the total number of tags N and the number of tags a given item can have M. The tag signature would be the IDs as an M-digit base-N number.

So if N = 50k and M = 3

tag 1 = 49,999
tag 2 = 1
tag 3 = 2

tag signature = 49,999 + 1 * 50,000 ^ 1 + 2 * 50,000 ^ 2 = 5,000,099,999

You'll need more than 64 bits to represent this. Use a large enough integer type to represent this value. Use more than one integer if necessary. Don't use floats, you will lose precision.

Comment: How can you do this if you want the signature to have a limited size, say a floating point number.

Comment: Where will they be stored? A database? How frequently do you want to read and write the tags for an item? How frequently do you want to search all items for a given set of tags? How frequently do you want to remove a single tag from all items? How many tags are there? How many items? How many tags per item?

Comment: Lets say 1M items, each has 10 tags, in total 50K different tags, stored in MySQL, tags and signatures are newer changed.

Comment: Please keep going. I asked about operations as well. You don't need to be very precise, just "rarely", "frequently", "never". Quoting myself: "How frequently do you want to read and write the tags for an item? How frequently do you want to search all items for a given set of tags? How frequently do you want to remove a single tag from all items?"

Comment: The tags for an item will never change. In general tags will never change. New items will be added frequently. The search by could be done frequently (if it is efficient), or infrequently (cached if it is not efficient).